# pipe, fork, how it is possible that program runs if and else of the same condition

Tags: c, if-statement, fork, pipe

Program runs once and it both throws data to the pipe and gets it out in the same condition that should be mutually exclusive (in if and else).
What I don't get here?
How does that work?
I have no experience with this kind of programming.

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <unistd.h>
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
```

Read characters from the pipe and echo them to stdout.

```
     void
     read_from_pipe (int file)
     {
       FILE *stream;
       int c;
       stream = fdopen (file, "r");
       while ((c = fgetc (stream)) != EOF)
         putchar (c);
       fclose (stream);
     }
```

Write some random text to the pipe.

```
     void
     write_to_pipe (int file)
     {
       FILE *stream;
       stream = fdopen (file, "w");
       fprintf (stream, "hello, world!\n");
       fprintf (stream, "goodbye, world!\n");
       fclose (stream);
     }

     int
     main (void)
     {
       pid_t pid;
       int mypipe[2];

       /* Create the pipe. */
       if (pipe (mypipe))
         {
           fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
         }

       /* Create the child process. */
       pid = fork ();
       if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
         {
           /* This is the child process.
              Close other end first. */
           close (mypipe[1]);
           read_from_pipe (mypipe[0]);
           return EXIT_SUCCESS;
         }
       else if (pid < (pid_t) 0)
         {
           /* The fork failed. */
           fprintf (stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
         }
       else
         {
           /* This is the parent process.
              Close other end first. */
           close (mypipe[0]);
           write_to_pipe (mypipe[1]);
           return EXIT_SUCCESS;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right after the line that says:

```
pid = fork();
```

You no longer have one program, but two distinct ones (when `fork` succeeds).

It's not the same program that runs both. In the child process, `fork` returns 0, but in the parent it returns the child PID.

The parent runs one branch of the `if`/`else` construct, the child runs another. (And a third is run, in the parent only, if `fork` fails.)

Comment: Which part of this code decides how many programs I will have running together? is it enough to change `int mypipe[2];` to `int mypipe[3];` in order to have 3 of them?

Comment: No, not at all. `pipe` doesn't create processes, `fork` does. You  get a new process each time you call `fork`. Be very careful with that and read the docs - if you end up calling `fork` in a loop or not being careful about what code you run in the child vs in the parent, you might end up with a "fork bomb". (Read up on that too.)